# In what sense, is `lvmdiskscan` deprecated,and we should use `pvs` instead?

Tags: lvm

`man lvmdiskscan` says

> lvmdiskscan scans all SCSI, (E)IDE disks, multiple devices and a bunch of other block devices in
>   the system looking for LVM PVs. The size reported is the real device size. Define a filter in
>   lvm.conf(5) to restrict the scan to avoid a CD ROM, for example.
>   **This command is deprecated, use pvs instead.**

`man pvs` says

> pvs produces formatted output about PVs.

The two commands list different kinds of things.
In what sense, is `lvmdiskscan`  deprecated,and we should use `pvs` instead?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you look for besides the man page itself saying so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both commands are intended to list PVs. `pvs` can be configured to list the same information as `lvmdiskscan` does by default:

```
pvs -a -o+dev_size
```

will list all devices with their size. Likewise, `lvmdiskscan` can be configured similarly to `pvs`’ defaults:

```
lvmdiskscan -l
```

will only list devices containing PVs.

`lvmdiskscan` is deprecated in favour of `pvs` because the latter can do everything `lvmdiskscan` can do and is far more flexible (see `man lvmreport` for details). `lvmdiskscan` also outputs some incorrect information in some circumstances (check its summary, in particular the count of “physical volume whole disks”).